# Question about a function return statement

Tags: python

I'm reading some python code to learn a application.

`FXRate` in below function is a wrapper class of 3 attributes: `cur`, `valdate`, `exchange`.
Could anyone enlighten me what the following function actually returns?

```
def proc(self, file_map, **options):
    fx_obj = []
    ...some processing to populate the fx_obj list...
    fx_obj += [FXRate(cur=..., exchange=...)
    return {FXRate: fx_obj}, []
```

Comment: It returns a tuple with the first element being a dictionary and the second element an empty list. The dictionary is using the class id as the dictionary key, the value for that key is a list of instances of that class. It is basically a mapper from a class to its instances.

Comment: Thank you for the very to-the-point answer. appreciated.